# Calculus Continuous or discontinuous

Tags: calculus

True or false. Does the function y=f(x)
  can not be continuous at only one point in its domain and discontinuous everywhere else. True or false

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the function $f$ defined by  $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational.